# What is the connection between Frechet Lie groups and Lie algebras?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, lie-groups, lie-algebras, frechet-manifold

An ordinary Lie group has a differentiable manifold structure, i.e. it is locally isomorphic to a finite-dimensional Euclidean space.  A Frechet Lie group, on the other hand, has a Frechet manifold structure, i.e. it is locally isomorphic to an infinite-dimensional Frechet space.

My question is, what is the connection between Frechet Lie groups and Lie algebras?  Wikipedia says [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_space#Fr%C3%A9chet_manifolds_and_Lie_groups):

> Some of the relations between Lie algebras and Lie groups remain valid in this setting.

But which ones remain valid and which ones don’t?

Answer (score 2):

Karl Hermann Neeb has lecture notes from a course on infinite-dimensional Lie theory given at a summer school in Monastir. They can be found for example [here](https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/wockel/data/monastir.pdf).

Comment: And together with Helge Glöckner he promised a two volume monograph on the subject... Still waiting.

Comment: I can also recommend his review [Towards a Lie theory for locally convex groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.06269).
Roughly speaking, the Lie functor still works in infinite-dimensions (i.e. going from Lie groups to Lie algebras) but the converse direction is more tricky.